# jquery chekbox selected

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm having some problems with jquery checkbox selected. I want to do a task when the checkbox is selected. my code for this is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('#chxGetText').is(':checked')) {
            alert("OK");
        }
    });

<input id="chxGetText" type="checkbox" />
```

But nothing happen when I check the checkbox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:checked` is just a selector, it doesn't bind any event listeners. Do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chxGetText').change( function (e) {
       if($(this).is(':checked')) {
          alert('Checked');
       }
       else {
          alert('Unchecked');
       }
    });
});

<input id="chxGetText" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: You’re using `function(e)` but you’re not using the `e`. Why not omit it?

Comment: i used this one removed the e like Mathias Bynens comment on. Not that is bothers the code just becuase it's not used. Thanks

Comment: @Mathias: I probably would in my own code unless I wanted to inspect or call methods on the event object. Just wanted to show that event handlers are passed an event object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind an event listener to the change event of the checkbox. Right now, you’re only checking if the checkbox is checked when the page loads, i.e. once.

```
$(function() {
 $('#chxGetText').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   alert('OK');
  } else {
   alert('Not OK');
  };
 }).trigger('change'); // trigger it on page load as well
});
```

Note that you should probably trigger the event on page load as well, in case the user refreshes the page after checking the checkbox (hence the `.trigger('change')` in my code).

Comment: Great code Mathias, I will be using the .trigger fosho on this other page i got

Answer (score 2):

You were not assigning an **event** to the element, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#chxGetText').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     alert("OK");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This will work, of course, but it’s probably a good idea to execute this check on page load as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643266/2643275#2643275

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like

```
jQuery("#chxGetText").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("#chxGetText is checked");
    }
    else {
        alert("#chxGetText is unchecked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign an event handler to the `onclick` event of the checkbox. Your current code only runs once, when the document is loaded and doesn't react to any state changes after that.

```
<input id="chxGetText" type="checkbox" />

function checkState(node) {
    if (node.checked) {
        alert("OK");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chxGetText').click(function() {
        // Bind checkState to click event
        checkState(this);
    }).each(function() {
        // Initial check on load
        checkState(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: using jquery and no obtrusive javascript?

Comment: You're right, I should've (or at least could've) skipped jquery in this solution altogether. I was merely trying to demonstrate why the original solution wasn't working as expected.

Comment: Err, no — you should’ve used unobtrusive JavaScript. jQuery or not.

Comment: The inline event, yes. But my intentions to demonstrate the problem with the original solution still stands. Revised anyhow.